# Percentile calculations on percentile ranks

Tags: ranking

I have a set 500 test scores which includes a national percentile ranking for each score. If I calculate a 50th percentile of the national percentile rankings, I get where the 500 test takers stand nationally as a group, in my case 67%. Now, I want to take a subset of those scores, say 150 of the students who took the test and enrolled.

My question is: if I calculated the 50th percentile of the 150 subset student's national percentile rank, would the result still represent an accurate ranking in relation to the national 50th percentile as a group?

Since I'm not a statistician, I am grateful for any help on understanding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which 150 scores do you want to pick- Is it done randomly or in any specific order ?

Here is my approach: 
If you want to pick a representative sample of 150 scores from population of 500 scores, then you can divide the scores into categories, say, 10-20,20-30,etc. and calculate proportion of scores in each category for sample and population, then run a chi-square test.

Maybe then, you can calculate percentiles and compare.